# C++ calling python Script that imports cv2 fails

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am trying to execute a simple python3 script from c++ code to load and display an image.

i created prog.py as follows:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

running this code using the command python3 prog.py works perfectly.

now i need to run this code from c++ (i know i can do the same in c++ but i need to add more functionalities to python code once i can make it work)

i wrote the c++ code as follows (NB: i am using QT)

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    char filename[] = "prog.py";
    FILE* fp;
    Py_Initialize();
    fp = _Py_fopen(filename, "r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, filename);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
    return a.exec();
}
```

The code compiles correctly but once i run it, it crashes.

I tried changing PYTHONPATH to /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (where pip install saves python-opencv) also it failed.

to make sure the code works i modified my pyhton code just to diplay hello world and without any imports and the c++ code works perfectly so the problem was with import cv2

is there something i am missing here?

as @KillPinguin mentioned did the following in prog.py

```
import os

print (os.getenv('path'))
print (os.getenv('pythonpath'))
```

running the code in both python and c++ give the following Output:

```
None
None
```

Comment: I **_cv2_** installed on any virtual enviroment?

Comment: Could you please provide the error message you get?

Comment: @eneski dont think so. all i did is i did sudo pip3 install opencv-python. (as you can clearly notice i am still a beginner in python)

Comment: @SashaTsukanov no error all i get is program crashed in QT application output and the terminal window show only press enter to close

Comment: You could try to print the environment `os.getenv('path')`, `os.getenv('pythonpath')` first from your system and then when called via C++. Maybe comparing these will give you a hint.

Comment: I guess if you remove `return 0;` it will at least run the Qt app

Comment: @KillPinguin i updated the question with the result of the prints

Comment: Sorry made a mistake - try to uppercase them - they're actually called `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @KillPinguin PYTHONPATH is None for both, the difference is in PATH. QT has the following 2 more than the output of python: /opt/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/bin:/usr/bin

Comment: so why won't you try removing the zero-return statement? In your current code the `a.exec()` is unreachable

Comment: @SashaTsukanov both with return 0 and without it cause the program to crashes. if i remove the return 0 statement when the program doesn't crash i need to CTRL+C to close it while with return 0 i get press enter to close and that's why i keep it

Comment: i removed opencv that i have installed using sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev and built it from source, the code worked. apparently there was something missing